# Android Data Binding Library in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android (IDE: Visual Studio 2015) and would like to work with the new Data Binding Library from Google.
Is it possible (and how)? Or is the Data Binding Library only available in Android Studio??

https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

Felix

Comment: some update about using this library with Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data-binding library is actually part of the gradle build toolkit so isn't available in Xamarin.Android applications. However there are plenty of data binding frameworks out there. MVVMLight, MVVMCross, Bind, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not available in Xamarin. Only android gridle have that data-binding library