# Can I use Android Data Binding Library in Xamarin.Android without gradle? Not MVVM for dotnet

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, data-binding, android-databinding

We have a app with Xamarin.Android and would like to work with Data Binding Library from Google.
How can we integrate this library to Visual Studio? is it possible?

https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

some year ago Felix ask for this
[Android Data Binding Library in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242965/android-data-binding-library-in-xamarin-android)

But only one answer suggest use MVVM libraries Xamarin.Forms-like, example MMVMLight
Arguing data-binding is part of gradle not msbuild

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281022/1669574

Comment: `MVVM Light bindings` is a good way, you could check the tutorial. https://mallibone.com/post/xamarinandroid-and-mvvm-light-bindings

Answer (score 1):

The biggest drawback for this library to work in **xamarin android** is that it is linked to the **gradle compilation**, Under the hood the data binding library generates several classes to update the interface at the time of changing the data.

For xamarin android the most recommended way is to use data binding is to use the native libraries for .net, for example MVVM Light, MVVM Cross, etc